# SLComposeViewController does not share image and url together

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook

I am trying to share a photo and URL on facebook using SLComposeViewController. Only the URL shows up in either the preview, and in the newsfeed.

1. If I share an image only, it works fine: image appears on the feed
2. If I share URL only, same result as when I do both, URL is shared to feed
3. I am fully aware that as per Facebook policy, initial text gets nuked, no matter what you put there, but this problem is not about that
4. I have exact same results with using directly FBSDKShareLinkContent or FBSDKSharePhotoContent

Seems like URL is overwriting whatever image content you want to share. I am using iOS 9.2, with Facebook app 50.0 installed on the device

Here is the code I am using:

```
SLComposeViewController *fbController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

//setting completion handler omitted

[fbController addImage:self.image]; //any image
[fbController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[self presentViewController:fbController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I bet if you share a URL the image is fetched from the og-tags on that URL

Comment: This is odd, I have the same issue with Facebook, but works fine with twitter.